# How to Join Rows SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-update

Its hard to explain my problem, so I added an image.

tblhistory:

[image: tblhistory]

I have `ReportedGMY` column in `tblother`. I need to update values into `ReportedGMY` and I have to save in `tblhistory` old `ReportedGMY` value and new `ReportedGMY` value.

First, I executed `INSERT INTO SELECT` query and save to `tblhistory` `ReportedGMY` value from `tblother`. And I updated `tblother` and changed values. Then, I inserted to `tblhistory` again.

Now, I need to carry up `OldValue` values with a query. Then delete null rows. How can do this? Or another way ?

Insert(second) query:

```
INSERT INTO tblhistory(FindingID, NewValue, [Date])
    SELECT 
        ID, ReportedGMY, GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime
    FROM
        (SELECT 
             ID, tblother.ReportedGMY,
             REPLACE(tblother.ReportedGMY, ' ', '') AS NewNumbers
         FROM
             tblother 
         INNER JOIN 
             tblother2 ON tblother.ReportID = tblother2.ID) A
    WHERE   
        A.ReportedGMY LIKE '%,Y,%' 
        OR A.ReportedGMY LIKE 'Y,%'  
        OR A.ReportedGMY LIKE '%,Y'
```

If I can write this query as `UPDATE`, the problem will be fixed I think. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a subquery here to return just the `FindingID` and `OldValue` where `OldValue` `IS NOT NULL`. These values are then used to update the rows that have `NULL` in `OldValue`.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.OldValue = b.OldValue
FROM TableName a
INNER JOIN (SELECT FindingID, OldValue FROM TableName where OldValue IS NOT NULL) b
    ON a.FindingID = b.FindingID
WHERE a.OldValue IS NULL
```

You can then get rid of data with a `null` in ChangeArea like this

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE ChangeArea IS NULL
```

Another option would be to extract all data into a temp table, truncate your table, then re-insert the data. Something like this (Assuming that your ID field is an `IDENTITY` field as it appears)

```
SELECT 
FindingID
,MAX(ChangeArea) ChangeArea
,MAX(OldValue) OldValue
,MAX(NewValue) NewValue
,MAX(Date) Date
INTO #TempTable
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FindingID

TRUNCATE TABLE TableName

INSERT INTO TableName (FindingID, ChangeArea, OldValue, NewValue, Date)
SELECT 
FindingID
,ChangeArea
,OldValue
,NewValue
,Date
FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

The advantage of this would be that you'll definitely only have one row per FindingID. The disadvantage is that if your table is large then you're going to be hitting tempdb quite hard and it may take a while to process.

Edit: To change that second statement to an update you'll want something like this;

```
UPDATE a
SET 
     a.ChangeArea = b.ReportedGMY
    ,a.NewValue = REPLACE(b.ReportedGMY, ' ','')
    ,a.Date = GETDATE()
FROM tblhistory a
INNER JOIN tblother b
    ON a.FindingID = b.FindingID
WHERE b.ReportedGMY like '%,Y,%' 
    OR b.ReportedGMY like 'Y,%'  
    OR b.ReportedGMY like '%,Y'
```

Comment: That's close to what I was going to answer. One thing to keep in mind would probably be the existence of duplicate `FindingId` values. But as long as their old values are alike this will probably only result in a couple of extra updates (though I'm not totally sure about this).

Comment: Yeah, totally valid concern. I've just updated my answer with a solution that will definitely only return one row of data per FindingID

Comment: @pseudocode I've just updated my answer to give you the update statement that I think you're after.

Answer (score 1):

This was a suggestion with an *updateable CTE*. This is completely untested air code... no warranties...

```
WITH ThisToUpdate(FindingIndex,FindingID,OldValue) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblother.FindingID ORDER BY tblother.ID) AS FindingIndex
          ,tblother.FindingID
          ,tblother.OldValue
    FROM tblother 
    WHERE tblother.OldValue IS NULL --or tblother.ChangeArea IS NOT NULL
)
,ValuesToUpdate(FindingIndex,FindingID,OldValue) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tblother.FindingID ORDER BY tblother.ID) AS FindingIndex
          ,tblother.FindingID
          ,tblother.ChangeArea
    FROM tblother
    WHERE tblother.OldValue IS NOT NULL --or tlbother.ChangeArea IS NULL
)
,Combined AS
(
    SELECT t1.*
          ,t2.OldValue AS NewValue 
    FROM ThisToUpdate AS t1
    INNER JOIN ValuesToUpdate AS t2 ON t1.FindingID=t2.FindingID AND  t1.FindingIndex=t2.FindingIndex
)
UPDATE Combined SET OldValue=NewValue;
```